# How would I update these class definitions of a singly linked list to implement a queue?

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, queue

I would like to know how to update/modify the following class definition to implement a queue. What class elements or methods would change?

Im preparing for my final exam and this is one of the questions asked on a previous exam that I answered incorrectly. My professor is adamant on using this specific class structure to implement a queue, however we did not go over it in class and it's not in our textbook either.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class StringNode{
private:
  string elem; 
  stringNode* next;

friend class StringLinkedList;
};
//Code fragment 1

class StringLinkedList{
public:
  StringLinkedList(){
   head == NULL;
}
  ~StringLinkedList();{
   while(!empty()){
    removeFront();
 }
}
  bool empty() const{
   return head == NULL;
}
  const string& front() const{
   return head->elem;
}
  void addFront(const string& e); 
  void removeFront();
private: 
  StringNode* head;
};
//Code fragment 2
```

Comment: Implementing a queue through a linked lists is done by either add-to-head and remove-from tail; Or add-to-tail and remove-from-head. At least one major changes to your list would make implementing a queue much simpler, and I'm certain you can figure it out if you think a little. :)

Comment: `~StringLinkedList();{` I'm pretty sure that's a typo, as is `stringNode* next`

Comment: The minimal change required to the above class to implement a queue would be the ability to add strings to the back of the list. As an Englishman I always join the back of any queue I see.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the tail of a singly linked list is an O(n) operation. *Unless* the implementation is properly encapsulated, and the internal structure of the list cannot directly be manipulated, in which case it would be possible for that implementation to safely keep track of the tail node of the list, allowing operations on the tail to be O(1).